# C# scandic letters to html format

Tags: c#, html

How to convert "ö" to "`&ouml;`" with C#?
I try to convert with `WebUtility.HtmlEncode` and
`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` methods, but they return "`&#246;`".
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this site (https://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/OumlCharacterEntity) the `&ouml;` character maps to the unicode value of `U+000F6` which is exactly the same as `0x246` (what .NET uses). Basically what .NET gives and what you are looking for are the same, then.

If you favor `&ouml;` semantically for some reason you would have to create an array of each of the replacements you want to make. From there you can use `string.Replace` on your html. If memory or performance are an issue you will probably need to look into using a StringBuilder. The LINQ version of `string.Replace` looks something like:

```
var myHtml = "long string with ö";
var encodedString = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(myHtml);

var replaceValues = new [] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("&#246;", "&ouml;") };
var encodedString = replaceValues.Aggregate(encodedString, (current, value) =>
                         current.Replace(value.Key, value.Value));
```

This is just *pseudocode* using LINQ and you may be able to optimize slightly but it gives you the basic idea. Best of luck!

Comment: For my task it not the same. I need method which convert exactly to ouml;

Comment: @user3608067 Could you explain why you need this exact behviour?